# Update Custom post field by Ajax on cached site

Tags: custom-field, ajax, cache, plugin-wp-supercache

My site cached by "wp-supper cache" plugin and "cloudflare.com"

So my php function to count post views working incorrectly.

I try to use ajax for it but I'm noob with JS code so I can not know where is wrong.

In **functions.php** I create a simple function:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'ajax_activation');
function ajax_activation(){
   //optional 
   wp_enqueue_script( 
      'ajax_script', 
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ajax.js', // path to your js file for ajax operations
       array( 'jquery' ), false
   );
   //end optional
   wp_localize_script( 
      'ajax_script', // the name of your global.js registered file
      'ajax_object', // name 
       array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) // you can add other items for example for using a translated string in javascript/jquery context
   ); 
}

add_action('wp_ajax_get_PostViews', 'get_PostViews');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_PostViews', 'get_PostViews');

function get_PostViews() {
$id = isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
$count_key = 'post_views_count'; 
$count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, true);
if( empty($count) ){ $count = 1; } else { $count++; }
update_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, $count);
}
```

Code in **ajax.js** file:

```
var postID = $(".view_detail").attr("id");
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // this is the object you defined in function.php
    data: {
       action: 'get_PostViews', // the name of your function
       id: postID // you can store it in html attribute for an easy access like: jQuery(element).attr('id');
    },
    success: function (result) {
    }
});
```

The **page.php** in my theme:

```
<div id="<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('view_detail'); ?>>
```

Please tell me how can I do it work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've spotted some errors here:

```
jQuery.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'. you can not set
     url: "http://localhost/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // if you have correctly enabled ajax in wp, you should use the object you set up with the url
     data: "{'action':'get_PostViews(" + idpost + ")'}", // you can use a PlainObject notation, so you don't need to double quoted. action property is the name of your function as you written in function.php
     success: function (result) {
       alert('Update Success!');
     }
});
```

Take a look here [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) .
To use ajax within WordPress follow these steps:

1. enable ajax functionality
2. declare your function in function.php
3. use javascript/jquery to send data to server and to listen data
   retrieved

**Enabling ajax**

The best way to accomplish that ( in my opinion ) is:

```
//File functions.php
    add_action('template_redirect', 'ajax_activation');
    function ajax_activation(){
       //optional 
       wp_enqueue_script( 
          'ajax_script', 
           get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ajax.js', // path to your js file for ajax operations
           array( 'jquery' ), false
       );
       //end optional
       wp_localize_script( 
          'ajax_script', // the name of your global.js registered file
          'ajax_object', // name 
           array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) // you can add other items for example for using a translated string in javascript/jquery context
       ); 
    }
```

**Declare function**

```
//File functions.php
add_action('wp_ajax_get_PostViews', 'get_PostViews');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_get_PostViews', 'get_PostViews');

function get_PostViews() {
    $id = isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
    // your code here
    wp_die(); // | die(); you need this to avoid trailing zero
}
```

**jQuery/Javascript**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl, // this is the object you defined in function.php
    data: {
       action: 'get_PostViews', // the name of your function
       id: // you can store it in html attribute for an easy access like: jQuery(element).attr('id');
    },
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```

I guess you are using this function for all posts in a loop, you can call ajax once to do the work for all posts. 
For example i want to retrieve with ajax the titles of my posts:

*HTML*

```
<html>
<!-- some stuff here -->
<h3 id="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>" class="spyhole"></h3> <!-- there are many of this :  ) -->
<!-- some stuff here -->
</html>
```

*jQuery*

```
ids = [];
items = $('.spyhole');
$.each( items, function( i, v){
    ids.push( $(v).attr( 'id' ) ); // each value is added to array
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: ajax_object.ajaxurl,
    data: {
      action: 'getMyTitleAjax',
      id: ids
    },
    success: function (result) {
      data = $.parseJSON( result ); // Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.
      $.each( data, function( i, v ){
        $('.spyhole[id="' + i + '"]').html( v ); // print the title
      });
    }
});
```

*PHP*

```
// Enabling ajax - functions.php
add_action('template_redirect', 'ajax_activation');
function ajax_activation(){
   //optional 
   wp_enqueue_script( 
      'ajax_script', 
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.ajax.js', // path to your js file for ajax operations
       array( 'jquery' ), false
   );
   //end optional
   wp_localize_script( 
      'ajax_script', // the name of your global.js registered file
      'ajax_object', // name 
       array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) // you can add other items for example for using a translated string in javascript/jquery context
   ); 
}

// Declare my function
add_action('wp_ajax_getMyTitleAjax', 'getMyTitleAjax', 3);
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_getMyTitleAjax', 'getMyTitleAjax', 3);
function getMyTitleAjax() {
    $ids = isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : false; // check if there is something in global $_POST
    if( $ids && is_array( $ids ) ){
      foreach( $ids as $id ){
        $titles[$id] = get_the_title( $id ); 
      }
    }
    echo json_encode( $titles ); // prints the result
    wp_die(); // avoid trailing zero
}
```

Hope it helps, if something is not clear feel free to ask

**Update**

According to your question updates, change this:

```
function get_PostViews() {
$id = isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
$count_key = 'post_views_count'; 
$count = get_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, true);
if( empty($count) ){ $count = 1; } else { $count++; }
update_post_meta($post_ID, $count_key, $count);
}
```

with this:

```
function get_PostViews() {
$id = isset( $_POST['id'] ) ? $_POST['id'] : false;
$count_key = 'post_views_count'; 
$count = get_post_meta($id, $count_key, true);
if( empty($count) ){ $count = 1; } else { $count++; }
update_post_meta($id, $count_key, $count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Emanuele - I will try again and tell you about the result.

Comment: Hi @Emanuele, I was edit my Question again with your answer but still not working. I want to +1 view for current post & page, not use in archive loop. What's wrong I have again? Thank you very much!

Comment: Add update take a look, let me know if it works @ZenNguyễn

Answer (score 0):

**single.php**

```
// ------------Post  views----------          
<script type="text/javascript">
    // get post views
    (function($) {
        function mostViews() {
             $.getJSON("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax.php",
                    {
                        action: 'get_mostViewedPost',
                        postid: <?php echo get_the_ID() ?>
                    }, function (data) {
                    })
        }
        var mostViews = new mostViews();
    })(jQuery);

</script>
```

**functions.php**

```
// ------------Post  views----------
// function to display number of posts.
function getPostViews($postID){
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
        return "0 View";
    }
    return $count.' Views';
}

// function to count views.
function setPostViews($postID) {
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
    if($count==''){
        $count = 0;
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    }else{
        $count++;
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);
    }
}

// Add it to a column in WP-Admin
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);
function posts_column_views($defaults){
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');
    return $defaults;
}
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){
    if($column_name === 'post_views'){
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());
    }
}

function postViews_callback(){
    setPostViews($_GET['postid']) ;
    echo "Success, Post id: ".$_GET['postid'];
    die();
}
add_action('ajax_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');
add_action('ajax_nopriv_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');

// -----------end Post views----------
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
//mimic the actuall admin-ajax
define('DOING_AJAX', true);

//make sure you update this line
//to the relative location of the wp-load.php

require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])))) . '/wp-load.php');
//Typical headers
header('Content-Type: text/html');
send_nosniff_header();

//Disable caching
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

$action = esc_attr(trim($_GET['action']));


//A bit of security
$allowed_actions = array( 
    'get_mostViewedPost'
);

//For logged in users 
add_action('ajax_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');
//For guests 
add_action('ajax_nopriv_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');

if(in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) {
    if(is_user_logged_in())
        do_action('ajax_'.$action);
    else
        do_action('ajax_nopriv_'.$action);
} else {
    die('-1');
}
```

Comment: Honestly: Dumping random code into an answer is no answer. Please take your time to explain things step by step.

Answer (score 0):

**single.php //post views**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">  
        // get post views  
        (function($) {  
            function mostViews() {  
                 $.getJSON("<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ajax.php",  
                        {  
                            action: 'get_mostViewedPost',  
                            postid: <?php echo get_the_ID() ?>  
                        }, function (data) {  
                        })  
            }  
            var mostViews = new mostViews();  
        })(jQuery);  

    </script>
```

**functions.php**

```
// ------------Post  views----------  
// function to display number of posts.  
function getPostViews($postID){  
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';  
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);  
    if($count==''){  
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);  
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');  
        return "0 View";  
    }  
    return $count.' Views';  
} 
// function to count views.  
function setPostViews($postID) {  
    $count_key = 'post_views_count';  
    $count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);  
    if($count==''){  
        $count = 0;  
        delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);  
        add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');  
    }else{  
        $count++;  
        update_post_meta($postID, $count_key, $count);  
    }  
} 

// Add it to a column in WP-Admin  
add_filter('manage_posts_columns', 'posts_column_views');  
add_action('manage_posts_custom_column', 'posts_custom_column_views',5,2);  
function posts_column_views($defaults){  
    $defaults['post_views'] = __('Views');  
    return $defaults;  
} 
function posts_custom_column_views($column_name, $id){  
    if($column_name === 'post_views'){  
        echo getPostViews(get_the_ID());  
    }  
} 
function postViews_callback(){  
    setPostViews($_GET['postid']) ;  
    echo "Success, Post id: ".$_GET['postid'];  
    die();  
}  
add_action('ajax_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');  
add_action('ajax_nopriv_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback'); 

// -----------end Post views----------
```

**ajax.php**

```
 <?php  
    //mimic the actuall admin-ajax  
    define('DOING_AJAX', true);  



    //make sure you update this line  
    //to the relative location of the wp-load.php  

    require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])))) . '/wp-load.php');
    //Typical headers  
    header('Content-Type: text/html');  
    send_nosniff_header();  

    //Disable caching  
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache');  
    header('Pragma: no-cache');  

    $action = esc_attr(trim($_GET['action']));  


    //A bit of security  
    $allowed_actions = array(   
        'get_mostViewedPost'
    );  

    //For logged in users   
    add_action('ajax_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');  
    //For guests 
    add_action('ajax_nopriv_get_mostViewedPost', 'postViews_callback');

    if(in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) {  
        if(is_user_logged_in())  
            do_action('ajax_'.$action);  
        else  
            do_action('ajax_nopriv_'.$action);  
    } else {  
        die('-1');  
    }
```

Comment: Please use the [WYSIWYG](http://xkcd.com/1341/) editor buttons to format your content. And: Please explain _why_ this answer is helpful.